# After duplicating an element the length property is incorrect using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unusual case and can't find a solution for this.
I'm trying to get the length of an column "Kontrolle".

The yellow background is the leader and is always on the first position and is duplicated from an other column.

This is the html code:

```
<div class="col-xl mr-2 py-0 content-kontrolle">
  <div class="header header-kontrolle">
     <h1 class="pl-2">Kontrolle</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="abt-kontrolle">

  <div class="mt-2 panel-name panel-kontrolle duplicate" data-name="Name 
      Name" data-status="leader">
    <div class="panel-img">
      <img src="" width="120" height="120">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-text ml-3">
      <p>
        <span class="panel-vorname font-book">Name</span>
        <br>
        <span class="panel-nachname font-bold"><strong>Name</strong></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-name panel-kontrolle mt-2" data-name="Name Name">
     <div class="panel-img">
        <img src="" width="120" height="120">
     </div>
     <div class="panel-text ml-3">
        <p>
          <span class="panel-vorname font-book">Name</span>
            <br>
          <span class="panel-nachname font-bold"><strong>Name</strong></span>
        </p>
     </div>
   </div>

  // and so on....


 </div>
</div>
```

if i check the length of this column i'm getting a wrong length.On the first photo there are 4 elements and i'm getting 3.

this is the jquery snippet:

```
var $abtLength = $('.abt-kontrolle .panel-name').length;
console.log($abtLength);
```

the length property is not counting the duplicate element.
[image]

if i check the `childElementCount` i get a correct length:
[image]

but when i console.log it i'm getting still wrong length.

```
var $childDepartmentNodes = $('.abt-kontrolle')[0].childElementCount;
console.log($childDepartmentNodes);
```

i'm getting also 3.

**UPDATE 1**

```
$("div[data-name='"+$name+"']")

                .not(".duplicate")

                .clone()

                .prependTo(".abt-"+ $belongsToDepartment + ":first")

                .attr("data-status", "leader")

                .removeClass(function(index, element) {
                    return (element.match (/\bpanel-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
                })

                .addClass("panel-name panel-" + $belongsToDepartment + " duplicate");
```

this is where i clone the leader from a column to another column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe your cloning/duplicating is not completely done at the moment when your log happens.

whats the count if you copy this

```
$('.abt-kontrolle .panel-name').length;
```

into dev console after everything is done?

Comment: thank you that helped me a lot ! i saved it into a seperate js file and wraped it into `$(window).on('load', function(){})` now the script is working.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, you can check attached snippet, but we need toi know how you duplicate the div maybe you get the size before duplacting the element

```js
var len = $(".abt-kontrolle>.panel-name").length;
alert(len)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xl mr-2 py-0 content-kontrolle">
  <div class="header header-kontrolle">
     <h1 class="pl-2">Kontrolle</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="abt-kontrolle">

  <div class="mt-2 panel-name panel-kontrolle duplicate" data-name="Name 
      Name" data-status="leader">
    <div class="panel-img">
      <img src="" width="120" height="120">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-text ml-3">
      <p>
        <span class="panel-vorname font-book">Name</span>
        <br>
        <span class="panel-nachname font-bold"><strong>Name</strong></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-name panel-kontrolle mt-2" data-name="Name Name">
     <div class="panel-img">
        <img src="" width="120" height="120">
     </div>
     <div class="panel-text ml-3">
        <p>
          <span class="panel-vorname font-book">Name</span>
            <br>
          <span class="panel-nachname font-bold"><strong>Name</strong></span>
        </p>
     </div>
   </div>
<div class="panel-name panel-kontrolle mt-2" data-name="Name Name">
     <div class="panel-img">
        <img src="" width="120" height="120">
     </div>
     <div class="panel-text ml-3">
        <p>
          <span class="panel-vorname font-book">Name</span>
            <br>
          <span class="panel-nachname font-bold"><strong>Name</strong></span>
        </p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-name panel-kontrolle mt-2" data-name="Name Name">
     <div class="panel-img">
        <img src="" width="120" height="120">
     </div>
     <div class="panel-text ml-3">
        <p>
          <span class="panel-vorname font-book">Name</span>
            <br>
          <span class="panel-nachname font-bold"><strong>Name</strong></span>
        </p>
     </div>
   </div>

 </div>
```